# Best way to display rounded corner image with sprite

Tags: directx, sprite

I need to display image with rounded corner with sprite. What is the best way to do this.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I explained how to do it in your other post ...

[How to clip the texture in rounded shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969493/how-to-clip-the-texture-in-rounded-shape)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean of smoothing the corners of the image you're drawing, there is no way to do with the normal sprite interface (other than modifying the original image to be smoothed beforehand)
To do it you must work with shaders.